# Why the regex that specifies a max length does not work in C# wpf

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I tried this regex but it doesn't work. I can write as many characters as I want without the validation stopping my entries. I would like to know why. In particular, if I remove the part that handles length, it works fine, but I need to handle length in my project. So I would like to know how to handle the maximum length in a c# regex

```
private void AlphaValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
     {
         if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]{0,10}$"))
         {
             e.Handled = true;
         }
     }
```

Comment: `but it doesn't work` ... how doesn't it work?

Comment: Set the maxlength property on the control and remove it from the regex? FWIW look into using MVVM if possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can continue writing without it stopping at 10 characters

Comment: And I prefer to do the management in the window's cs page rather than in my ViewModel

Comment: Have you checked `e.Text.Length`, print it out to console... Checks like these belong in the VM.

Comment: I have just seen that it remains blocked at 1, which is not normal, even though I have entered several letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried this regex but it doesn't work. I can write as many characters as I want without the validation stopping my entries. I would like to know why. In particular, if I remove the part that handles length, it works fine, but I need to handle length in my project

Long story short, the `e.Text` is the partial issue, especially coming from the `TextCompositionEventArgs`.

When a user types something into that textbox, the event will be kicked off, *but* will only contain the value the user entered, not any other previous entered text. In order to check what the user previously entered plus the **new value**, you would need to concatenate two separate properties.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch((e.Source as TextBox)?.Text + e.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]{0,10}$"))
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

In the above example, I am using `e.Source` which is the textbox itself and its current text (before this new value), plus the **new value**. The is the exact reason why you're only getting a length of one.

Please note, there are other ways to validate data as well, but not related to this post and would be too long.

Comment: Thanks to you for your complete answer. And thank you to the others who put minuses when I have modified my question to make it clearer. People are very understanding...